# SQL Server login issue with sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, azure-synapse

I am trying to run a file in Ubuntu using the `sqlcmd` command as shown below. We have a complex password set as per standards. Using that I am getting an error saying that "Login failed for the user "username" ".

```sh
sqlcmd -S ${servername} -d ${dbname}  -U ${sqlusername}  -P ${sqlpassword} 
       -I -i ${inputfile} -s"|" -r1 1>${logfile} 2>${errorfile}
```

I tried to execute the same by providing values with password in single quotes. It worked fine

As we cannot hard code the password. I tried the things shown here, but those didn't work.

```sh
sqlcmd -S ${servername} -d ${dbname} -U ${sqlusername} -P '${sqlpassword}'
sqlcmd -S ${servername} -d ${dbname} -U ${sqlusername} -P "${sqlpassword}"
sqlcmd -S ${servername} -d ${dbname} -U ${sqlusername} -P \'${sqlpassword}\'
```

Can someone please help me - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your password (or any of the other parameters to be honest), by any chance, contain a `$` character? If so, that's why. Bash doesn't like them.

Comment: It has dollar sign in it. Thank you.

Comment: @user_297020, can you change the password to solved the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for @Larnu's comment.

The error caused by your password has has dollar sign in it.